# Word for women who happily does not care about feminism for romantic

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

I am looking for a word or a phrase describe a women who does not care about feminism, especially when she is in love. It's not she doesn't aware it, or think it useless, or she sacrifices herself for something more important (e.g. her child); it just she accepts to take a step back because she feels that will be romantic. For instance, maybe she is a person who normally fighting for her right in the office, but when she is in a relationship, she would like to let her partner holds her bag, or buy her ice cream, because in that case she will find that she is in cared.

Comment: As @oaker said, there's no single word, but some hint at it. How I would express this concept depends enormously on the context.  I would put that concept very differently in a personal ad vs. in an article about dating behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of a single word that means what you're asking. I would simply describe this woman as someone who prefers traditional gender roles in relationships.